# In odd/even question if we provide very large value (like up to 12 digits ) then there are error in program;

Tags: input, output

In odd/even question if we provide very large value (like up to 12 digits ) then there are error in program;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"This program is for finding if the provided integer is even or odd.\nPls provide the integer...\n";
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    if(a%2==0){
        cout<<"The provided integer is even.";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"The provided integer is odd.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum value (a 32 bit) `int` can take in C++ is 2,147,483,647. So, 12 digits can't be handled by `int` – use `long int` or `long long int`, instead.